# Reactjs: How to prevent child from modifying props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running into a strange issue where a component is updating a variable in the parent component that was passed to it as a prop.

The structure looks vaguely like so:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  const toPassToChild = [{ name: 'name', val: 0 }];
  ...

  render() {
    return(<ChildComponent p={toPassToChild} />);
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      ...
      arrayOfObjects: this.props.p
    }
  }

  modifyState() {
    let aCopy = [...this.state.arrayOfObjects];

    let member = aCopy.find(element => {
      return element.name === 'name';
    });

    member.name = 'foo';

    this.setState({
      arrayOfObjects: aCopy
    )};
  }
}
```

When `modifyState()` is called, the value of `toPassToChild` is changed in `ParentComponent` to `[{name: 'foo', val: 0}]`. Is there any way to stop this? The issue does not occur with other props that are used as initial state, only the prop which is an array of objects.

Comment: Need to understand that while `aCopy` is a different array than `arrayOfObjects` they each contain the same object references as elements. Modifying an object in either one will be reflected in the other since they contain the same objects

Comment: I see, I didn't realize objects were always references. So making a copy of `member` then adding that back into the array should solve it?

Comment: Yes...or mapping whole `aCopy` to new objects using `Object.assign()` or `Object.create()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify `member.name` in `modifyState`, you're mutating the original object, since `[...this.state.arrayOfObjects]` still contains the references to the original objects.

Here's how you can update the array without mutating the original:

```
modifyState() {
  const arrayOfObjects = this.state.arrayOfObjects.map(obj => {
    if (obj.name === 'name') {
      return { ...obj, name: 'foo' };
    }
    return obj;
  });

  this.setState({ arrayOfObjects });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change the way you copy in the child component. `[...]` only makes copy of first level elements.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  const toPassToChild = [{ name: 'name', val: 0 }];
  ...

  render() {
    return(<ChildComponent p={toPassToChild} />);
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      ...
      arrayOfObjects: this.props.p
    }
  }

  modifyState() {
    let aCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.arrayOfObjects));

    let member = aCopy.find(element => {
      return element.name === 'name';
    });

    member.name = 'foo';

    this.setState({
      arrayOfObjects: aCopy
    )};
  }
}
```

Check the link for working version https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kxtvoi?file=index.js